# How to integrate $\int \frac{1}{\sin^4(x)\cos^4(x)}\,\mathrm dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

How can I integrate $$\int \frac{1}{\sin^4(x)\cos^4(x)}\,\mathrm dx.$$

So I know that for this one we have to use a trigonometric identity or a substitution. Integration by parts is probably not going to help. Can someone please point out what should I do to evaluate this integral?

Thanks!

Comment: The Maple command $$Student[Calculus1]:-IntTutor(1/(sin(x)^4*cos(x)^4), x)  $$ finds it step by step with explanations. See [here](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=examples/Calculus1SingleStepping) for info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int \frac{16}{16 \sin^4(x)\cos^4(x)}dx  &= 16 \int \frac{1}{(2 \sin(x)\cos(x))^4} dx \\
&= 16 \int \csc^4(2x)dx \\  
& = 16 \int \csc^2(2x) \csc^2(2x)dx\\ 
&= 16 \int  (1 + \cot^2(2x)) \csc^2(2x) dx \\ 
&= 16 \int \csc^2(2x)dx + 16 \int  \cot^2(2x)\csc^2(2x)dx \\  
&= \; \;\dots \\
&= \; \; \dots \\
\end{align*}

For the last let, $\cot(2x) = u$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Substitute $t=\tan x$.

> Then $\frac{dx}{\sin^4 x \cos^4 x} = \frac{(1+t^2)^3}{t^4}dt$.

Answer (score 1):

All integrals of rational functions of $sin(x)$ and $cos(x)$ can be solved by rationally parameterizing the unit circle ( see http://mathnow.wordpress.com/2009/11/06/a-rational-parameterization-of-the-unit-circle/  for example). This will convert the integral into a rational integral, which are all solvable by partial fraction decomposition.  Try this out for the infamous $\int sec^3(x)dx$ for instance.